# gtkmm: Cannot create Gtk::Switch

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

Using Gtkmm 2.24.5, I'm trying to create a window with a single `Gtk::Switch` with the following code:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <gtkmm/switch.h>

class SimpleWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    SimpleWindow();
private:
    Gtk::VBox m_VBox;
    Gtk::Switch m_Switch;
};

SimpleWindow::SimpleWindow()
{
    set_title("Simple");
    add(m_VBox);
    // Todo: Setup switch
    show_all();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Gtk::Main kit(argc, argv);
    SimpleWindow simple;
    kit.run(simple);
    return 0;
}
```

When trying to run the code, I get the following warnings and errors:

```
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 11:21:22.896: cannot register existing type 'GtkWidget'
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 11:21:22.896: cannot add class private field to invalid type '<invalid>' 
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 11:21:22.896: cannot add private field to invalid (non-instantiatable) type '<invalid>' 
GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:21:22.896: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INSTANTIATABLE (instance_type)' failed 
GLib-GObject-WARNING **: 11:21:22.896: cannot register existing type 'GtkBuildable' 
GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 11:21:22.896: g_type_interface_add_prerequisite: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_INTERFACE (interface_type)' failed 
GLib-CRITICAL **: 11:21:22.896: g_once_init_leave: assertion 'result != 0' failed
```

After removing the switch from the class definition, the program runs just fine, returning an empty window. What is the problem here?

Comment: Which Gtkmm version are you using?

Comment: `std::cout << GTKMM_MAJOR_VERSION << "." << GTKMM_MINOR_VERSION << "." << GTKMM_MICRO_VERSIONl;` gives 2.24.5

Comment: It seems `Gtk::Switch` was [introduced in Gtkmm 3.0](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Switch.html#details). Its weird that your application even builds with it as a member variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that I used gtkmm 2.24.5, while `Gtk::Switch` was introduced with gtkmm 3.0. Somehow my pkg-config eclipse plugin also included gtkmm 4.0, so the explicit include of `gtkmm/switch.h` prevented a compiler error at the `m_Switch` declaration.

Switching to a clean project with gtkmm 4.0 the new minimum working example for the `Gtk:Switch` class looks like this:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

class SimpleWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    SimpleWindow();
private:
    Gtk::Switch m_Switch;
};

SimpleWindow::SimpleWindow()
{
    set_title("Simple");
    m_Switch.set_margin(20);
    set_child(m_Switch);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create("org.gtkmm.example");
    return app->make_window_and_run<SimpleWindow>(argc, argv);
}
```

Which compiles and runs now as expected.

Comment: Please consider accepting your answer for other users to see.